# execute code behind method every time DIV loads (ASP, ascx, ascx.cs)

Tags: asp.net, css, ascx

The idea is that this div contains a quote from a customer that is retrieved from the server via a get random function, and every few seconds a jQuery runs that fades this quote out and brings another one into view.

**This is my Div code in my .ascx:**

```
< div class="testimonial" ID="Fader" onload="runTestimonial">

<q>"<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Quote"></asp:Literal>"</q>

</div>
```

**Code Behind (.ascx.cs):**

```
protected void runTestimonial(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ --lots 'o code--

Partnership partnership = Partnership.GetRandomTestimonial(cmPage.CMPageId);
            if (partnership != null)
            {
                Quote.Text = partnership.Testimonial;
                Visible = true;
            }
}
```

**I am using this jQuery code:**

```
setInterval(
    (function () {
        $('#Fader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#Fader').load().fadeIn('slow'); }, 300);
        });
    })
    , (200))
```

The jquery should be fine.  It links into the Div's Fader ID and does the fading and loading.

Originally the div generated the quote using a Page_Load method of the same structure and this worked.  Now the change is I need to call it when I need to, not on Page_Load but on jQuery refresh.

So far I have the div refreshing in and out, but it's blank (If I revert it to the on Page_Load method, the same quote comes in and out). It's not getting to the ASP line or it's not executing it.  I can just not get runTestimonial to work at all like the Page_Load does, probably because I don't know how to call it.

I don't know how to do C#, jQuery ASP or code behinding stuff really.  Please  help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps of what you need to do, with jQuery and WebMethod:

1) You will change your `runTestimonial()` function into a `WebMethod` that will return a string (the random testimonial). So your function's signature would look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string runTestimonial()
{
    return randomTestimonial; //include your code
}
```

2) Add jQuery library in the head of your file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

3) Create a function that will do an ajax call to your webmethod.

```
function getTestimonial()
{
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Default.aspx/runTestimonial",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
       $("#Fader").html(msg); //msg contains the response from the server, this appends it to the div
     }
   });
}
```

4) Your div in your markup will NOT be a server control, so remove the `onload`. So it will look like this:

```
<div class="testimonial" ID="Fader"></div>
```

5) We are almost done, just make sure to call your `getTestimonial()` function inside your setInterval.

The `[WebMethod]` attribute is found in the `System.Web.Services` library, so make sure to include it at the top of your page:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

That's all, that should work.

Comment: : O  That is a lot of work, thank you sir.  I started playing with it.  So far I am just having difficulty putting everything in webmethod without getting errors.  I might have to continue troubleshooting tomorrow but I will tell you how it goes!

Comment: I've been playing with it and still have trouble.  I wonder if it has something to do with the url?  The page I'm working on now is an ascx; basically this is just the quote nugget that any page who inherits the master will display.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it should have anything to do with the URL, the WebMethod should be accessible from there as well. But maybe try doing it in the same page and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you : )  It did involve some ajax and some other tricks; this website ended up being so complicated it involved changing a lot of things.  I had to get an on-call senior developer to help me.  I was hoping to do it (mostly)myself and be cool but it didn't happen, haha.  Thank you for your time.  Marking this as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, C# is server side, so the method `runTestimonial` doesn't exist on the client's browser. You need to create a javascript function that uses jQuery to call to the server with an ajax request. I would suggest checking out some tutorials on jQuery/ajax/ASP.Net. It seems like you are missing some of the fundamentals. Hope that helps!

Comment: That's a lot of steps.  I've been staring at assorted how-to's for a few days.  One of the problems is I'm expected to solve this but I don't know the basics of really any of these languages, so it's hard to build off of 3 different foreign foundations all at once lol.  I wish I knew atleast one of them well.
Ajax looks really complicated, hmm.  What do you think I should look at first?

Comment: You're probably looking at low level ajax, if you are doing ajax with jQuery, it's pretty easy: `$.ajax({})`

Comment: I'm looking at it..  I'm not sure what to do with it.